# Как ускорить запрос на обновление двух таблиц?

Tags: mariadb, оптимизация, mysql

Упрощенная ситуация. MySQL, две таблицы (*table1* и *table2*) с одинаковой структурой:

```
id     - первичный ключ
person - фамилия
check  - булево значение (изачально 0)
```

Нужно пометить те записи, которые есть в обеих таблицах. По идее, здесь нужен такой запрос:

```
    UPDATE table1 AS a
INNER JOIN table2 AS b
        ON a.person = b.person
       SET a.check  = 1, 
           b.check  = 1;
```

Однако при объёме таблиц в 30-40 тыс. записей время выполнения запроса несколько огорчает. Как ускорить процесс?

Как решение мне видится последовательное выполнение запросов типа:

```
    UPDATE table1 AS a
INNER JOIN table2 AS b
        ON a.person = b.person
       SET a.check  = 1, 
           b.check  = 1
     WHERE a.person LIKE 'а%' 
       AND b.person LIKE 'а%';
```

Не факт, что копаю в правильном направлении. Поэтому хотелось бы узнать, какие еще есть подходы.

Comment: индексы есть по person? строки сравнивать - всегда медленно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про одно ускорение я уже писал в связанной задаче (добавить индекс на check и условие where check = 0), здесь немного расскажу про другое ускорение.

Как уже сказали, сравнивать строки - это медленно. Даже наличие индекса (b+tree) плохо поможет. Но ведь для этого поля можно использовать и хэш-индекс - по сравнению с обычным сравнением значительно ускорит выборку (хотя чтение с диска все равно будет происходить).

Как вариант, можно эмулировать работу хэш-индекса - создаем еще одно поле, по нему b+tree индекс, и храним в этом поле хэш-функцию от исходного поля. Тогда перед сравнением строк мы сравниваем их хэш-индексы. От сравнения строк не уйти, т.к. возможны коллизии, но скорость все равно должна быть выше, чем индекс по строке.

И еще - а зачем вам person? Почему нельзя во второй таблице указывать не его, а числовой id из первой таблицы? Это будет намного быстрее тех же хэш-индексов или индексов по строке.

Таким образом получаем:
- используем вместо person ключ id
- добавляем check в условие
- добавляем индекс по check (если InnoDB, то хватит его одного, без связки с id)

Тогда скорость выполнения значительно ускорится + будет меньше неприятных сюрпризов в виде зависших других запросов (при чем не только из-за возросшей скорости)

P.S. тема старая, но ведь это может и другим пригодиться ))