# СУБД: что происходит во время выполнения запроса?

Tags: mariadb, оптимизация, база-данных, mysql

В продолжение [вопроса про обновление двух таблиц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/290733/mysql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86).

Что делает СУБД при выполнении такого запроса:

```
    UPDATE table1 AS a
INNER JOIN table2 AS b
        ON a.person = b.person
       SET a.check  = 1, 
           b.check  = 1;
```

- сначала ищет все данные, удовлетворяющие условиям, потом джойнит их и после этого обновляет?

*или:*

- для каждой записи в *table1* пытается найти соответствие в *table2* и (если соответствие найдено), обновляет записи, а потом переходит к следующей записи?

Имеет ли смысл добавление в запрос условий:

```
WHERE a.check = 0
  AND b.check = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

А у Вас только часть `person` из `table1` существует в `table2`?

Я имею в виду, что если все `table1.person` присутствуют в `table2`, то можно просто сразу установить `table1.check` в 1. И наоборот (для `table2`).

Если это не так, то можно попробовать разбить на 2 запроса

```
update table1 where person in (select person from table2) set check = 1
update table2 where person in (select person from table1) set check = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понял из исходников - mysql сначала join`ит таблички, создает во временных таблицах новые значения, а потом копирует в исходные таблицы из временных. При этом одну из таблиц он может обновить "на лету".

Но в вашем запросе другая проблема: mysql блокирует строки (если InnoDB), он может даже заблокировать больше чем вам действительно надо. Поэтому в вашем случае как минимум будут заблокированы все строки, в которых person есть в обеих таблицах. А значит во время обновления другие запросы будут топтаться на месте в ожидании конца обновления.

Хорошо бы количество таких строк уменьшить, причем не только добавив условие с check, но и добавив индекс по тому полю (для InnoDb этого будет достаточно).

При этом мы не только уменьшим количество заблокированных строк, но и значительно ускорим выборку таблиц для обновления (я надеюсь, что `check = 0` будет достаточно редким явлением)

Comment: не пашут такие ссылки, лучше plain text'ом...  
http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/5.6/view/head:/sql/sql_update.cc